# envoy rewrite x-forwarded-for header

Tags: proxy, envoyproxy

I set in config file

```
  use_remote_address: true
  xff_num_trusted_hops: 0
  skip_xff_append: false
```

and got x-forwarded-for with real client-IP, but if I set x-forwarded-for on client-side (in Postman), for example: "my_IP_address" then I get on server side in headers:

```
x-forwarded-for: my_IP_address,192.168.1.47
```

Please help, how config envoy to rewrite this header? Thanks!